# Making a help bot that is in the bottom right corner

Tags: javascript, html, bots

[The website link](https://sites.google.com/view/coin-gang-web/home) [The bot image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bF8o0.png) I am making a website, and I have the chat parts, and some examples in the code, but I cant get a square, or an image, I need the image to be in a square, in the bottom left. And if there is any way to shorten it, please do so. The code snippet does work, but it says theres an error, this is already on my website.

```js
 $(function() {
            var trigger = [
              ["hi","hey","hello"], 
              ["how are you", "how is life", "how are things"],
              ["what are you doing", "what is going on"]
            ];
            var reply = [
              ["Hi","Hey","Hello"], 
              ["Fine", "Pretty well", "Fantastic"],
              ["Nothing much", "About to go to sleep", "Can you guest?", "I don't know actually"],
            ];

            println('Bot: ' + trigger[1][0]);

            var alternative = ["Haha...", "Eh..."];

            let textInput = $('#txt-inp');
            let messageOutput = $('#out');
            let processingStatus = $('<span>Bot: Processing...<br></span>');
            let name = 'cds1170';
            function println(text) {
              let newSpan = document.createElement("SPAN");
              let newLine = document.createElement("BR");
              let textNode = document.createTextNode(text);
              newSpan.appendChild(textNode);
              document.getElementById("out").appendChild(newSpan);
              document.getElementById("out").appendChild(newLine);
              gotoBottom();
            }
            function print(text) {
              let newSpan = document.createElement("SPAN");
              let textNode = document.createTextNode(text);
              newSpan.appendChild(textNode);
              document.getElementById("out").appendChild(newSpan);
            }
            function gotoBottom() {
              window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight);
            }
            function sendMessage() {
              let data = {
                'reply': textInput.val()
              };
              if (!data['reply']) {
                return;
              }
              println(name + ': ' + data['reply']);
              textInput.val('');
              messageOutput.append(processingStatus);
              textInput.attr('disabled', 'disabled');
              messageOutput.children().last().remove();
              textInput.removeAttr('disabled');
              output(data['reply']);
            }
            $('#txt-inp').keypress(function(e) {
              if (e.which == 13) {
                sendMessage();
              }
            });

            function output(input){
              try{
                var product = input + "=" + eval(input);
              } catch(e){
                var text = (input.toLowerCase()).replace(/[^\w\s\d]/gi, ""); //remove all chars except words, space and 
                text = text.replace(/ a /g, " ").replace(/i feel /g, "").replace(/whats/g, "what is").replace(/please /g, "").replace(/ please/g, "");
                if(compare(trigger, reply, text)){
                  var product = compare(trigger, reply, text);
                } else {
                  var product = alternative[Math.floor(Math.random()*alternative.length)];
                }
              }
              println(product);
            }

            function compare(arr, array, string){
              var item;
              for(var x=0; x<arr.length; x++){
                for(var y=0; y<array.length; y++){
                  if(arr[x][y] == string){
                    items = array[x];
                    item =  items[Math.floor(Math.random()*items.length)];
                  }
                }
              }
              return item;
            }
          });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container" id="content"> 
    <p id="out">
    </p>
    <p id="inp">
        <span id="dir">Message: </span>
        <div id="stretchbox">
            <input type="text" 
                   id="txt-inp"
                   autocomplete="off"             
                   autocorrect="off"
                   autocapitalize="off" 
                   autofocus="autofocus"
                   spellcheck="false">
            </input>
        </div>
    </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

```html
<html>
    <body>
        <div class="container" id="content"> 
            <p id="out">
            </p>
            <p id="inp">
                <span id="dir">Message: </span>
                <div id="stretchbox">
                    <input type="text" 
                           id="txt-inp"
                           autocomplete="off"             
                           autocorrect="off"
                           autocapitalize="off" 
                           autofocus="autofocus"
                           spellcheck="false"
                    />
                </div>
            </p>
        </div>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
          $(function() {
            var trigger = [
              ["hi","hey","hello"], 
              ["how are you", "how is life", "how are things"],
              ["what are you doing", "what is going on"]
            ];
            var reply = [
              ["Hi","Hey","Hello"], 
              ["Fine", "Pretty well", "Fantastic"],
              ["Nothing much", "About to go to sleep", "Can you guest?", "I don't know actually"],
            ];

            println('Bot: ' + trigger[1][0]);

            var alternative = ["Haha...", "Eh..."];

            let textInput = $('#txt-inp');
            let messageOutput = $('#out');
            let processingStatus = $('<span>Bot: Processing...<br></span>');
            let name = 'cds1170';
            function println(text) {
              let newSpan = document.createElement("SPAN");
              let newLine = document.createElement("BR");
              let textNode = document.createTextNode(text);
              newSpan.appendChild(textNode);
              document.getElementById("out").appendChild(newSpan);
              document.getElementById("out").appendChild(newLine);
              gotoBottom();
            }
            function print(text) {
              let newSpan = document.createElement("SPAN");
              let textNode = document.createTextNode(text);
              newSpan.appendChild(textNode);
              document.getElementById("out").appendChild(newSpan);
            }
            function gotoBottom() {
              window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight);
            }
            function sendMessage() {
              let data = {
                'reply': textInput.val()
              };
              if (!data['reply']) {
                return;
              }
              println(name + ': ' + data['reply']);
              textInput.val('');
              messageOutput.append(processingStatus);
              textInput.attr('disabled', 'disabled');
              messageOutput.children().last().remove();
              textInput.removeAttr('disabled');
              output(data['reply']);
            }
            $('#txt-inp').keypress(function(e) {
              if (e.which == 13) {
                sendMessage();
              }
            });

            function output(input){
              try{
                var product = input + "=" + eval(input);
              } catch(e){
                var text = (input.toLowerCase()).replace(/[^\w\s\d]/gi, ""); //remove all chars except words, space and 
                text = text.replace(/ a /g, " ").replace(/i feel /g, "").replace(/whats/g, "what is").replace(/please /g, "").replace(/ please/g, "");
                if(compare(trigger, reply, text)){
                  var product = compare(trigger, reply, text);
                } else {
                  var product = alternative[Math.floor(Math.random()*alternative.length)];
                }
              }
              println(product);
            }

            function compare(arr, array, string){
              var item;
              for(var x=0; x<arr.length; x++){
                for(var y=0; y<array.length; y++){
                  if(arr[x][y] == string){
                    items = array[x];
                    item =  items[Math.floor(Math.random()*items.length)];
                  }
                }
              }
              return item;
            }
          });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please explain your answer (I didn't downvote it).